# Xamarin Forms Scheduled Notifications/Reminders

Tags: forms, xamarin, notifications, reminders

I have been tasked with creating a Xamarin Forms app feature which creates reminder notifications when certain recurring tasks must be performed. These task schedules will be maintained by a back-office system and will need to be synced with a group of Android devices.

These are the approaches I’m considering:

•   Firebase Cloud Messaging to push out task notifications from the back-end in real-time (or according to the schedules if this is possible with FCM).

•   Syncing the task schedules with the devices somehow and using AlarmManager or similar to trigger the notifications.

Any thoughts of which approach would work best, or is there an alternative I haven’t considered?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by a web service that store store the task with timestamp in some store of DB. You will have to create a service that queries the DB, Lets say every n minutes and sends push notification using FCM for all the task that are scheduled for that particular time. Obviously this approach will not be precise to milliseconds but it will work for sure no hiccups. To achieve milliseconds level of precision you will have to do a lot more work than this.